# Persist multiple states using LocalStorage in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage

I need to persist multiple states in Redux store using `LocalStorage`. I already have working one key in my case it is drivers. also need to do with buses and carriers states.

**Store.js**

```
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import Reducers from './reducers';
import { loadState, saveState } from '../../utils/localstorage';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

// LOCAL STORAGE FOR DRIVERS, BUSES, CARRIERS

const persistedState = loadState()

const store = createStore(
  Reducers,
  persistedState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      ReduxThunk
    )
  )
);

store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState({
    drivers: store.getState().drivers
  });
});

export default store;
```

**localstorage.js**

```
export const loadState = () => {
  try {

    const serializedDriversState = localStorage.getItem('drivers')

    if (serializedDriversState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedDriversState);
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined;
  }
};

export const saveState = (drivers) => {
  try {
    const serializedDriversState = JSON.stringify(drivers);
    localStorage.setItem('drivers', serializedDriversState)
  } catch (err) {
    // Ignore errors.
  }
}
```

I'm using Dan Abramov's example: [Redux LocalStorage](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage).

So how to store multiple states using LocalStorage in Redux store? Is it good approach or use some middleware like [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)?

Comment: What is the issue with your current solution ?

Comment: I need to add two more states(buses, carriers), setted locaStorage item multiple times with those keys, but getting same first value in all keys what i writed in store.subscribe(() => { saveSate({ }) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should add forEach over state in store.subscribe function and you can save the whole store partly.

```
export const saveState = (key, data) => {
  try {
    const serialized = JSON.stringify(data);
    localStorage.setItem(key, serialized);
  } catch (err) {
    // Ignore errors.
  }
}

store.subscribe(() => {
    const state = store.getState();
    Object.keys(state).forEach( key => {
      saveState(key, state[key])
    })
});
```

Comment: This is solution for my problem. Acepteed & marked this answer as useful.